# Increasing timeout of poltergeist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I need to increase the length of the timeout in Poltergeist.
The poltergeist documentation says I need to put this code in my test setup

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, options)
end
```

I am new to testing I am not sure where the test setup. 
I am using Rpsec and Capybara. Could somebody help out please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work:

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, timeout: 1.minute)
end
```

Are you having long running javascript or ajax?

https://coderwall.com/p/aklybw/wait-for-ajax-with-capybara-2-0 and http://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara - how to handle ajax

There is also a way to disable animation in tests, to make it run faster. And if you have some elements with `position: fixed` then poltergeist will see text behind it as invisible.